# C linux daemon does not write into file after opening FIFO

Tags: c, linux, daemon, fifo

I have following program in C, which should run as a deamon and whenever is something written into FIFO, it should write it into a file.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#define BUF_LENGTH 255

volatile int signal_flag = 1;

void signal_handler(int sig)
{
    signal_flag = 1;
}

char *getTimeString()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    char *timeStr = asctime (timeinfo);
    timeStr[strlen(timeStr) - 1] = 0;

    return timeStr;
}

void printUsage()
{
    printf("Usage: syslog_daemon PATH INTERVAL\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* print usage */
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printUsage();
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    /* process arguments */
    char *logFilePath = argv[1];
    int interval = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* establish the signal handler */
    struct sigaction action;

    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    action.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

    /* initialize variables */
    int fd;
    /*char buf[BUF_LENGTH];
    int length;*/
    int msgs = 0;

    /* Create FIFO if not created */
    if (mkfifo("/tmp/pb173_syslog", 0766) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Making FIFO failed with error %d\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Run */
    daemon(1, 1);
    while(1)
    {           
        /* Open FIFO */     
        fd = open("/tmp/pb173_syslog", O_RDONLY);
        close(fd);

        /* Open and write into file */
        FILE *f = fopen(logFilePath, "a");
        fprintf(f, "Daemon write: %d\n", msgs);
        fclose(f);


        /* Process SIGALRM and write syslog */
        if(signal_flag)
        {                   
            openlog("syslog_daemon v2", LOG_CONS, LOG_DAEMON);
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Messages written: %d\n", msgs);
            closelog();

            msgs++;

            signal_flag = 0;
            alarm(interval);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this program does not write anything into the file. It seems, that when the FIFO is open, it cannot write anywhere. But if I don't open the FIFO, the program writes into the file without any problems. Does anyone know what is the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your program blocks at open system call? If yes, then make sure you open fifo at both ends. Open system call goes into blocking mode if fifo is not opened for both read and write.

Comment: You open the FIFO, and then immediately close it without reading anything from it.  How does your daemon get anything to write to the secondary file?

Answer (score 3):

It hangs on `open` trying to open a FIFO which does not have the second endpoint (the writer) connected.
You may want to use `O_NONBLOCK`.

Here is a quote from `strace` output that shows where it hangs:

```
$ strace -p 23114
Process 23114 attached - interrupt to quit
open("/tmp/pb173_syslog", O_RDONLY
```

If you write something to the FIFO (e.g. `echo test > /tmp/pb173_syslog`) it unblocks and starts working.